# org.testng.TestNGException: Error creating object factory

Tags: testng, powermock, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to compile a maven project on IntelliJ (Ubuntu 22.04), but during a specific test this happened:

```
...
[ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Error creating object factory: class com.project.AbstractClassTest
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Error creating object factory: class com.project.AbstractClassTest
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:656)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:282)
...
```

Inside the surefire report, the following appears:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Error creating object factory: class com.project.AbstractClassTest
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.createObjectFactory(TestNGClassFinder.java:277)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:115)
...
```

What could possibly lead to a TestNGException exception with the message "Error creating object factory" being thrown while running TestNGClassFinder.createObjectFactory?
`AbstractClassTest` extends the `PowerMockTestCase` class from Powermock, which contains a @ObjectFactory annotated method.

maven version: 3.6.3
jdk: 1.8.362
surefire version: 2.22.2
testng version: 6.14.3
powermock: 1.7.4

I've tried downgrading surefire and testng versions on the main pom file but that didn't help.
I've tried deleting my local repo file, invalidating caches and running `mvn clean install` multiple times, but still no success.
Running the `mvn clean install` command with -DskipTests does return build success in all modules, but it's still supposed to return build success having ran all tests. It has to be related with my environment specifically and not with the code per se because all my colleagues have no trouble running the tests, using the exact same project repo I use.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your 'AbstractClassTest' class code and pom.xml? Looks like some mismatch in the package name or config issue with the dependencies.